# OpenApi Swagger not showing Exception as a response

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I'm using OpenApi Swagger UI (v. 4.14) with SpringBoot. I'm getting all the info I need with the Swagger, except for the exception. Here's my code.

**Garage class:**

```
@Schema(description = "Details about the Car")
@Document("Garage")
public class Garage implements Serializable {


    @Schema(description = "An ID of the car in the database", accessMode = Schema.AccessMode.READ_ONLY)
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Schema(description = "The name of the car")
    @Field("model")
    protected String carModel;
    @Schema(description = "Car's engine power output")
    protected Integer hp;
    @Schema(description = "Production year of the car")
    @Field("Year")
    protected Integer year;
    @Schema(description = "The name of car's designer")
    protected String designer;
   
// controllers, getters, setters, toString
```

**Controller:**

```
// some other code

   @Operation(summary = "Deletes a car by its id")
   @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200",
                    description = "A car is deleted from the Garage",
        content = {@Content(
                schema = @Schema(implementation = Garage.class),
                mediaType = "application/json")}),
           @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404",
                   description = "A car with this id is not in our garage",
                   content = @Content(
                           schema = @Schema(implementation = RestExceptionHandler.class),
                           mediaType = "application/json"))})
    @DeleteMapping(path = "/deleteCar/{carId}")
   public void deleteCarFromGarage(@PathVariable("carId") String id) {
        garageService.deleteFromGarage(id);
   }

// some other code
```

**Exception handler:**

```
@Schema(description = "Exception handling")
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {

    @Schema(description = "The ID is not valid")
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {IllegalArgumentException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> resourceNotFoundException(IllegalArgumentException exception) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I'm getting 200 responses every time, no matter do I delete a correct id, or an incorrect one.

**EDIT: here's my deleteFromGarage method**

```
public void deleteFromGarage(String id) {
    garageRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the code of `garageService.deleteFromGarage(id)`?

Comment: @Helen yes, sure! I've edited my post, adding that method.

Comment: Ok, and how does `garageRepository.deleteById(...)` look like? How does the code handle non-existing `id`?

Comment: It doesn't have any code. It just deletes an object by an Id. That's my issue, I don't know how to handle it so the exception ends up in Exception handler.

Comment: @Helen >> Just to inform you, your questions have guided me to the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited my deleteFromGarage method, and that solved the issue

deleteFromGarage before:

```
public void deleteFromGarage(String id) {
    garageRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

deleteFromGarage now:

```
public void deleteFromGarage(String id) {
    if (garageRepository.findById(id).isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The ID is not valid");
    } else {
        garageRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```